# SwiftUI - stacking views like the notifications on the Lockscreen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, notifications

I am trying to stack views of my app like the notifications on the lockscreen. (See attachment) I want them to be able to stack by clicking the button and expand on a click on the view. I have tried many things on VStack and setting the offsets of the other views but without success.

Is there maybe a standardized and easy way of doing this?
Somebody else have tried it and has a tip for me programming this?

Thanks

[Notifications stacked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaNev.png)
[Notifications expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCYBP.png)

EDIT:

So this is some Code that I've tried:

```
VStack{
            ToDoItemView(toDoItem: ToDoItemModel.toDo1)
                .background(Color.green)
                .cornerRadius(20.0)
                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                .padding(.bottom, -1)
                .zIndex(2.0)
            
            ToDoItemView(toDoItem: ToDoItemModel.toDo2)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(20.0)
                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                .padding(.bottom, -1)
                .zIndex(1.0)
                .offset(x: 0.0, y: offset)
                
            ToDoItemView(toDoItem: ToDoItemModel.toDo3)
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .cornerRadius(20.0)
                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                .padding(.bottom, -1)
                .offset(x: 0.0, y: offset1)
            
            ToDoItemView(toDoItem: ToDoItemModel.toDo3)
                .background(Color.gray)
                .cornerRadius(20.0)
                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                .padding(.bottom, -1)
                .offset(x: 0.0, y: offset1)
            
            ToDoItemView(toDoItem: ToDoItemModel.toDo3)
                .background(Color.pink)
                .cornerRadius(20.0)
                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                .padding(.bottom, -1)
                .offset(x: 0.0, y: offset1)
        }
        
        
        Button(action: {
            if(!stacked){
                stacked.toggle()
                
                withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5)) { self.offset = -100.0 }
                
                withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5)) { self.offset1 = -202.0 }
            }
            else {
                stacked.toggle()
                
                withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5)) { self.offset = 0 }
                
                withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5)) { self.offset1 = 0 }
            }
        }, label: {
            Text("Button")
        })
```

So the first problem is that view 4 and 5 are not stacked on z behind view 3.
The second problem is that the button is not getting under the 5th view. (the frame/VStack of the views is still the old size)

[Views stacked vertical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQa6W.jpg)
[Views stacked on z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg5hS.jpg)

Comment: There is no "standard" way to achieve this, but it is certainly doable in SwiftUI. On SO, it's better to show some code that you've tried and then ask questions about where you got stuck. Can you update your post with one of your attempts?

Comment: @jnpdx Added some code and pictures :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it a little easier to get exact positioning using `GeometryReader` than using `ZStack` and trying to fiddle with offsets/positions.

This code has some numbers hard-coded in that you might want to make more dynamic, but it does function. It uses a lot of ideas you were already doing (`zIndex`, `offset`, etc):

```
struct ToDoItemModel {
    var id = UUID()
    var color : Color
}

struct ToDoItemView : View {
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).fill(Color.clear)
            .frame(height: 100)
    }
}


struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var stacked = true
    
    var todos : [ToDoItemModel] = [.init(color: .green),.init(color: .pink),.init(color: .orange),.init(color: .blue)]
    
    func offsetForIndex(_ index : Int) -> CGFloat {
        CGFloat((todos.count - index - 1) * (stacked ? 4 : 104) )
    }
    
    func horizontalPaddingForIndex(_ index : Int) -> CGFloat {
        stacked ? CGFloat(todos.count - index) * 4 : 4
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { reader in
                ForEach(Array(todos.reversed().enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index, item) in
                    ToDoItemView()
                        .background(item.color)
                        .cornerRadius(20)
                        .padding(.horizontal, horizontalPaddingForIndex(index))
                        .offset(x: 0, y: offsetForIndex(index))
                        .zIndex(Double(index))
                }
            }
            .frame(height:
                        stacked ?  CGFloat(100 + todos.count * 4) : CGFloat(todos.count * 104)
            )
            .border(Color.red)
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    stacked.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                Text("Unstack")
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `ZStack` if your interested.

***Note-:***

I have declared **variables**  globally in `view`, you can create your own `model` if you wish.

```
    struct ContentViewsss: View {
    
    @State var isExpanded = false
    
    var color :[Color] = [Color.green,Color.gray,Color.blue,Color.red]
    var opacitys :[Double] = [1.0,0.7,0.5,0.3]
    var height:CGFloat
    var width:CGFloat
    var offsetUp:CGFloat
    var offsetDown:CGFloat
    
    init(height:CGFloat  = 100.0,width:CGFloat = 400.0,offsetUp:CGFloat = 10.0,offsetDown:CGFloat =  10.0) {
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.offsetUp = offsetUp
        self.offsetDown = offsetDown
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
            ZStack{
                ForEach((0..<color.count).reversed(), id: \.self){ index in
                    
                    Text("\(index)")
                        .frame(width: width , height:height)
                        .padding(.horizontal,isExpanded ? 0.0 : CGFloat(-index * 4))
                        .background(color[index])
                        .cornerRadius(height/2)
                        .opacity(isExpanded ? 1.0 : opacitys[index])
                        .offset(x: 0.0, y: isExpanded ? (height + (CGFloat(index) * (height + offsetDown))) : (offsetUp * CGFloat(index)))
                }
                
                Button(action:{
                    withAnimation {
                        if isExpanded{
                            isExpanded = false
                        }else{
                            isExpanded = true
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                } , label: {
                    Text(isExpanded ? "Stack":"Expand")
                }).offset(x: 0.0, y: isExpanded ? (height + (CGFloat(color.count) * (height + offsetDown))) : offsetDown * CGFloat(color.count * 3))
                
            }.padding()
            
            Spacer().frame(height: 550)
        
    }
}
```